# How would one import only a single value from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I know that you can use "from foo import bar", however, this still actually imports all of the data. The reason why I know this is because I have a file containing variables, with one of those variables containing a lot of data. To give a pseudo example, let's say the variable in question is foo and it contains numbers 1-100,000,000, it takes about 2 minutes to load in all these numbers.

Again this is just an example, the actual data is much more complex.

Anyway, other variables are just single digits or small lists or directories. Yet when I try to import any of these, it takes just as long as if I was trying to import all of the data in foo. Again this is true even when using "From foo import bar" notation.

The only solution I can think of is to store these variables in separate files, and then read only what I need from the set of files when I need to, thus, whenever I need to import something, unless it's variable foo, it won't take a long time.

Of course, this isn't as neat as storing the variables in a single file, so I was wondering if there was a way I could do this without having to import everything at once?

I will say that when imported once, it only takes about two seconds to run the program again, which is fine, however, I need to import said data within multiple modules, so this design I have right now is very much suboptimal.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Related [thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function). Seems like there might not be a better way to do this than having your big data in a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module, it is interpreted (the module script is executed). All you can do in to use a proxy for your peculiar heavy variable. Note that, in normal usage, a module is a singleton, so it is loaded only once. The `from foo import bar` is only a way to store a variable reference in the `globals()` scope.

See:

- [“The import system”](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) in the documentation.
- The lazy submodule imports in [“PEP 562 -- Module `__getattr__` and `__dir__`”](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/#rationale)

Quote about the lazy submodule imports:

```py
# lib/__init__.py

import importlib

__all__ = ['submod', ...]

def __getattr__(name):
    if name in __all__:
        return importlib.import_module("." + name, __name__)
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")

# lib/submod.py

print("Submodule loaded")
class HeavyClass:
    ...

# main.py

import lib
lib.submod.HeavyClass  # prints "Submodule loaded"
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see, so I guess the from foo import bar technique is good for resolving name clashes, and for convenience (so you don't have to always do foo.bar). 

I always thought it was for that but also to save load time because I thought it was just analyzing the value for whatever variable it was importing. How would you go about setting up a proxy for the variable and/or data? I've never heard of that before myself, but it seems interesting.

Comment: @JimJam, there are several ways to implement a cache/proxy/lazy import. See my edit for a modern approach.